# how to get dict value by regex in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

```
dict1={'s1':[1,2,3],'s2':[4,5,6],'a':[7,8,9],'s3':[10,11]}
```

how can I get all the value which key is with 's'?
like `dict1['s*']`to get the result is `dict1['s*']=[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [x for d in dict1 for x in dict1[d] if d.startswith("s")]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11]
```

or, if it needs to be a regex

```
>>> regex = re.compile("^s")
>>> [x for d in dict1 for x in dict1[d] if regex.search(d)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11]
```

What you're seeing here is a nested [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's equivalent to

```
result = []
for d in dict1:
    for x in dict1[d]:
        if regex.search(d):
            result.append(x)
```

As such, it's a little inefficient because the regex is tested way too often (and the elements are appended one by one). So another solution would be

```
result = []
for d in dict1:
    if regex.search(d):
       result.extend(dict1[d])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import chain
def natural_sort(l): 
     # http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734/846892
     convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
     alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
     return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)
...
```

Using **glob** pattern, `'s*'`:

```
>>> import fnmatch
def solve(patt):
    keys = natural_sort(k for k in dict1 if fnmatch.fnmatch(k, patt))
    return list(chain.from_iterable(dict1[k] for k in keys))
... 
>>> solve('s*')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11]
```

Using `regex`:

```
def solve(patt):
    keys = natural_sort(k for k in dict1 if re.search(patt, k))
    return list(chain.from_iterable( dict1[k] for k in keys ))
... 
>>> solve('^s')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried below hope it help you, by getting the keys of dictionary and then if the first index of the key is your start with character then extend the list with the key dictionary list.

```
n='s' # your start with character
result=[] # your output

for d in dict1.keys():
    if n == d[0]:
        result.extend(dict1[d])

print result
```